# What's the seconde moment of a T beam with a heel?

Tags: moment-of-inertia, inertia

the seconde moment of area of a rectangle is 
Iy = (bh^3)/12

b : base
h : height

What is the second moment of area of a T beam like this one ?
[image]

Comment: The fundamental question here is what are the area properties if a trapezoidal shape. If you can answer that, you can assemble the above beam section.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the contribution of the heels only (assuming you know how to calculate the area moment of a webbed shape).

Using the dimensions below, you need to find out

1. The area of the heel, $A$.
2. The centroid of the heel, $y_c$.
3. The area moment about the origin, $I_A$.
4. The area moment about the centroid, $I_C = I_A - A\, y_c^2$.

[image: Sketch]

We define the line  $y(x) = (h_1+h_2) - h_2 \left( \frac{x - b_a/2}{b_{ta}/2-b_a/2} \right) $ where the heel terminates along the *y*-axis and parametrize the area as follows:

[image: setup]

Then the total area of the heels are

$$A = 2 \int \limits_{b_a/2}^{b_{ta}/2} y\,{\rm d}x = \left( b_{ta} - b_a \right) \left( h_1 + \tfrac{1}{2} h_2 \right)  $$

The centroid of the heel is located at

$$ y_c = \frac{1}{A} 2 \int \limits_{b_a/2}^{b_{ta}/2} (\tfrac{y}{2}) y\,{\rm d}x = \frac{3 h_1^2 + 3 h-1 h_2 + h_2^2}{3 (2 h_1 + h_2)} $$

The area moment about the origin is

$$ I_A = 2 \int \limits_{b_a/2}^{b_{ta}/2} \left( \tfrac{A}{12} y^2 + A x^2 \right) y\,{\rm d}x = \frac{A (b_{ta}-b_a)}{48} \Bigl( 4 h_1^3+6 h_1^2 h_2 + 4 h_1 (h_2^2+b_a^2+b_a b_{ta} + b_{ta}^2) + h_2 (h_2^2+3 b_a^2 + 2 b_a b_{ta} + b_{ta}^2)\Bigr) $$

<sub>The area moment of thin sliver is $I = \frac{ b h^3}{12} = (b h) \frac{h^2}{12}$.</sub>